# Prevent other git authors

Tags: linux, git

I have setup my own private git server, and have a team of 5 members. I have their user accounts all setup, but how do I prevent commits to the remote being done by random weird accounts. Because some of my team also use github and wouldn't want their usernames appearing in the log, but rather their username I assign them.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/117006/251311

Comment: Not the same... I basically want some sort of authentication method.. So my team can't be committing as other team mebers simply by going git --config.name = "Test"

Comment: @MaraisRossouw In that case, you will have to use gerrit or gitlab or some other such tool.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent people committing using "random weird accounts", you could set up a git `pre-receive` hook to validate the commiter/author names on incoming commits against a list of valid names.  But this doesn't provide the authentication component.

To prevent impersonation, you could simply required that all commmits are gpg-signed (`git commit -S ...`), and have you `pre-receive` hook validate the signatures against a gpg keyring on the server.

Depending on how people are connecting to your remote server, you could also explicitly match the commiter/author name against the username used for the connection, if you have access to that.

**Update 1**

If your committers are pushing to your server over ssh, then the third option above is probably the easiest.  In your `.ssh/authorized_keys` file, set an environment variable for each key that identifies the user:

```
environment="SSH_USER=lars" ssh-rsa ...
```

And then in your `pre-receive` hook, you can use that environment variable to look up valid committer names/emails against some table.  You can read about `pre-receive` hooks in the `githooks(5)` man page, they receive on stdin a lines of the form:

```
<oldrev> <newrev> <refname>
```

You can get the commit name from `<newrev>` like this:

```
commiter_name=$(git show -s --format='format:%cn' <newrev>)
```

And the mail using `%ce` instead of `%cn`.

**Update 2**

Or heck, just forget table lookups. In your `.ssh/authorized_keys` file:

```
environment="ALLOWED_NAME=Bob Jones",environment="ALLOWED_EMAIL=bob@example.com" ssh-rsa ...
```

And then in your pre-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read oldrev newrev refname; do
  cn=$(git show -s --format='format:%cn' $newrev)
  ce=$(git show -s --format='format:%ce' $newrev)

  [ "$cn" = "$ALLOWED_NAME" ] || {
    echo "*** Inalid committer name"
    exit 1
  }

  [ "$ce" = "$ALLOWED_EMAIL" ] || {
    echo "*** Inalid committer email"
    exit 1
  }

done
```

And I think you have what you want.

**Update 3**

You could probably accomplish something similar using http
authentication, because within your `pre-receive` script you would
have access to the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable, which contains
the name of the authenticated remote user.  You would probably need to
go with some sort of table lookup to get value of approved names and
email addresses.

Comment: Ok. Yes i have a linux account setup for each committer, how do i validate gpg signatures with their login? And how would a pre-receive look like? And as i have quite a number of repos, would i have todo this for each repo?

Comment: I've updated the answer a bit.  If you decide to go the `gpg` route, it would probably involve `grep`ing the output of something like `git show -s --format=format:'' --show-signature <rev>` for `Good signature`.

Comment: I updated it again.  I think I like this solution better. It's simpler to implement, at least.

Comment: Ok, but now.. What if instead of an ssl key authentication, my team use just plain passwords. Can you do something similar? Or more so, can you direct me as to how to setup ssl type authentication.

Comment: Not `SSL`, just `SSH`.  There are lots of guides out there on setting up key-based authentication with ssh.  You can't do the same thing with password-based authentication, because there's no mechanism to have the server set per-user environment variables in this case.

Comment: Ok awesome. Is there other ways of pushing other than ssh?

Comment: Well, sure, there are lots of ways you can push to a git repository, *if* the administrator has configured them (via `http` if you've set that up, or via write access on the local filesystem).  But you have control over that.

Comment: Ok. So can you still do the author validation with http pushing?