# Enforcing and creating Git policies

Tags: linux, git, githooks

I have been tasked with changing Git a bit, and have failed to find anything of relevance on the interwebs - and I am in dire need of directions.

What we have:
a bunch of branches, with the main being `test` (basically `develop`) and `master` branches. `master` is untouched most of the times.

Now, I have created a continuous integration environment using TeamCity, Jira and Crucible as well as a service written by myself.

What we want to achieve:

1. disallow pushing to `test` - unless it's TeamCity
2. reject push on feature branch if the Jira issue of id==branchName is in wrong state

Now, 
ad1) I have no clue how is such a thing achieved. I might be simply misunderstanding what Git helpers were saying to me, but as I read, I can either disallow completely, or allow completely.

ad2) is nominally easy, as I understand a pre-push hook script has to be used, but it also has to be placed on each dev's local git repository, or can I enforce that somehow?

Comment: Are you using gitlab or github to host your repos?  Each supports what you're looking for.  I'm not sure if you can do what you want with a raw repo.

Comment: -I am using github - clarified in the title-

Comment: Actually  i was wrong, we have a raw repo hosted on ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @chicks said, you can absolutely get the features you want using something like GitLab.  User restrictions (as in "only `teamcity` has write-access to this branch") are available out of the box, and there is generally support for server-side hooks that you could use to implement your second requirement.

It's certainly *possible* to implement the same restrictions on your own, simply serving out git repositories over ssh, but it requires some development effort on your part.  The general model is:

- Configure `.ssh/authorized_keys` for your `git` user to include metadata that can be used to identify the user associated with an incoming push,
- Write Git hook scripts to perform the per-branch access control or policy enforcement.

There are examples of doing these things here and there; for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401926/prevent-other-git-authors) is an older answer I wrote describing how to ensure that the email address on commits matches the identity of the connecting user.

Using a pre-packaged solution like GitLab will almost invariabely make more sense than trying to roll-your-own.

Comment: It took a while for me to process this, so basically  instead of blocking pushing altogether, I should create a pre-push hook script that will block pushes from certain users, while allowing others.

Thanks!

Comment: So, for the record, a `pre-push` script runs on the *client* side, and is useless for *enforcing* policy (because a client can simply disable it, either intentionally or simply by not enabling it when cloning the repository).  For policy enforcement you need server-side hooks like `pre-receive` or `update`.

Comment: I have just found that out. I have successfully created a bash script using pre-push hook, so now I just need to convert it to pre-receive hook :)
Thanks a bunch.

For the record, I have used bash only (!/bin/bash), and I am calling jira with curl.