# How to find actual committer in git?

Tags: git, github

Recently, one of my colleague used my email & name in `.gitconfig` for pushing the code in `master` branch (Ethically wrong, but it was mostly for fun). As `git` takes the name from config, instead of actual `ssh` or login, rest of them are seeing my name in commit.

As changing config is easy & doesn't require any authentication/authorization. I want to know, is there a way through which I can differentiate actual me from the fake me?

**Note**: My colleague & I've similar rights to push in repo. Actually, it is same for all the devs in our team. Most of us uses `ssh` way of pushing in git.

Comment: The ssh connection should have been logged in `/var/log/wtmp`. Otherwise, should you need commit authentication, you can use signed commits in your repository.

Comment: Relevant: https://mikegerwitz.com/papers/git-horror-story

Comment: @spectras can you please elaborate more on `signed commits`?

Comment: It's about using GPG to add a personal, cryptographically secure signature to each of your commits. Someone else wouldn't be able to sign the commit with your key. It's part of git core features. [This page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work) of the git documentation shows the basic principles of how to use it.

Comment: You will need to read the link. Commit signing is complex. There are some serious annoyances with signing every commit, too. There are tradeoffs in all choices here, but I think the "right place" to do authentication for *most* users is during commit transfer. That is, when `fetch`ing, you should inspect the incoming commits and determine whether you trust them before you merge them or use them. When `push`ing, you should have the receiving system inspect the incoming commits and determine whether to trust them before accepting them.

Comment: @spectras I guess, there is a issue with it. My colleague can always skip `-s` while committing, isn't it? And it would still imply, I did it. Or do you suggest me to user `-s` ALWAYS, so that I can be sure that nobody else has it?

Comment: @Abhishek> anyone can skip the `-s`. It just means the commit should not be trusted, neither the (probably faked) author nor the content. Basically when you use signed commits, an unsigned commit is a red herring: someone untrusted tampered with the repository.

Comment: Got it! I would start using this way of committing from now. Thanks for letting me know, a new way :)

Comment: @spectras (and Abhishek): note that `-s` just adds a *text* line saying "Signed-off-by".  It's `-S` (uppercase S) that PGP-signs the commit.

Comment: @torek> true, and important difference. I always confuse them and use the long version, `--gpg-sign` to be safe.

Comment: @torek yup.. Got it :)
@spectras
My follow up question, Can I force every commit to have `-S` otherwise the user will not be able to push the code? If this is possible, then it might be a full proof way, unless user start sharing his/her keys.

Comment: @Abhishek: You can control absolutely everything *if* you have full control over the repository. So this means you can control *your* repository, but not anyone else's copy, unless you also control that copy. If you `git push` to some server, you must have sufficient control over the server so that you can control *its* copy. Then you can use a `pre-receive` or `update` hook to do this. If you have only partial control, then it depends on how much you trust whoever else also has control. (Side note: the English word you want here is "foolproof".)

Comment: @torek I guess, I can influence our team maintainer (our git admin) to change the settings, if they are valid. So, can you please point me to the direction where I can force user to have signed commits always?

Comment: @Abhishek: I don't have such a script myself.

Comment: @torek Ok.. I'm in process of creating one. Thanks for all the pointers

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, your colleague was in the wrong when he identified himself as you, whatever the action - should have been preformed as his own named user for the sake of an audit trail.

That being said - if that user had the correct privileges to push code to the repo (as his own named user), and there were no hooks setup to validate that the incoming commit matched the person doing the push - then I would say that **no**, there is no way to differentiate between who made these commits.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/642182/1790644) is a pre-receive hook that will validate that the person pushing the code, is also the author listed in the commit.

Comment: `pre-receive` hooks.. I wasn't aware of anything like this! Let me check and get back :)

Comment: Ahh yes, there are several [hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) you can create validation scripts for; some client side, some server side.

Comment: In this script, I can still add other username and password in `authors` variable & then script will fail, correct? I mean, it is not fullproof or am I missing something?

Comment: The scripts listed in that answer, correct, take a list of approved authors, so you can still have issues; but this whole questions is kind of a catch-22 situation; if you prevent an author from pushing any commit that they did not author, that means no two people will be able to work on the same feature branch, because then no single person would be able to merge it; which requires person A pushing person B's commits.

Comment: oh.. So, do you imply there is no full proof way? I mean, shouldn't it be simple for git to check for validity of email from the ssh key. I mean, is there a flag or something like `strict` push which I can set and then all the commits will be checked by git.

Comment: In other words, whenever I commit. Git should be able to check if the email is added to my account or not. If it is not, then don't allow user to push and whenever a email is added send a email to that email, that it has been added in xyz account. I mean, that would be a full proof way.

Comment: @Abhishek> thing is it is a completely valid use of git to clone your repository for your colleague, work together both of you and in the end have one of you merge your work to a remote server. In this scenario one of you will be pushing the other's commits. If the server disallows that, your work cannot be merged back at all.

Comment: @spectras then this might not be a good idea, as there is a easy workaround :(. I think signed commits makes more sense. But there is still one piece of information missing. Can I force signed commit always?

Comment: It's misleading to say validating commit author against push-er makes collaboration impossible.  It would limit the usable workflows.  If dev 1 pushes commit A, then dev 2 pushes commit B (with parent A), then dev 1 pushes commit C (with parent B), etc. etc... at the end merging is just creating a new commit (with two parents) which itself would have to be pushed by who created it. That it merges commits created (and pushed) by someone else doesn't matter. But workflows where devs 1 and 2 swap commits directly and then want to merge and push the whole thing at once to origin, would be trouble.

Comment: That said, validating whose pushing is also imperfect in that it requires you always push in a way that the push-er can be verified. If you're going to make assertions about identity, signing the commit itself preserves flexibility in who delivers the commit to this repo or that repo. If, that is, you *really* are concerned that someone could pass of a bad patch and claim it came from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Places I've worked haven't found a need to authenticate the author of a commit.  If you do have this need, then you need to sign the commits.  See the `--gpg-sign` option of `git commit`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Comment: So, can I force user to have force signed commit always? If yes, what is the way?

Comment: Your origin repo could reject pushes that have unsigned commits (using git hooks).  The hook could call `git verify-commit` on each new commit in the push, which I believe will return a non-0 status if the commit isn't signed.  See *git hooks* documentation for how to set this up.